# How do we remove elements from a MutableList in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have the following code where I need to display the elements of a list in view and then remove those items from the list. I have been looking into filter vs map in kotlin but no luck finding a solution.

```
var mutableList: MutableList<Object> = myImmutableList.toMutableList()
for (x in mutableList.indices)
{
    val tile = row!!.getChildAt(x % 4)
    val label = tile.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
    label.text = mutableList[x].name
    val icon = tile.findViewById(android.R.id.icon) as ImageView
    picasso.load(mutableList[x].icon).into(icon)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are iterating through the whole list, simplest way would be to call [clear method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/clear.html) of `MutableList` after you process all items.

```
mutableList.clear()
```

Other option could be method [remove](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove.html) to remove given element or [removeAt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-at.html) to remove element at given index. Both are again methods of [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) class. In practice it would look like this.

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c")
val mutableList = list.toMutableList()
for (i in list.indices) {
    println(i)
    println(list[i])
    mutableList.removeAt(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't just map and filter the initial immutable collection? You are already making a copy when you call "List#toMutableList()", so I don't quite see what you're trying to accomplish by avoiding it.

```
val unprocessedItems = myImmutableList.asSequence().mapIndexed { index, item ->
    // If this item's position is a multiple of four, we can process it
    // The let extension method allows us to run a block and return a value
    // We can use this and null-safe access + the elvis operator to map our values
    row?.getChildAt(index % 4)?.let {
        val label = it.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView

        label.text = item.name
        val icon = it.findViewById(android.R.id.icon) as ImageView

        picasso.load(item.icon).into(icon)

        // Since it's processed, let's remove it from the list
        null
    } ?: item // If we weren't able to process it, leave it in the list
}.filterNotNull().toList()
```

Again, not quite sure what you're going for with this. I think there might be a better approach given more detail.